# Turn array into a POCO object

Tags: c#, asp.net, poco

I'm having trouble converting the following string array into a POCO object.
Given the following:

```
string files = [
  "./Folder/file.ext",
  "./Folder/file2.ext",
  "./Folder/file3.ext",
  "./Folder/nestedfolder/file.ext",
  "./Folder2/file1.ext",
  "./Folder2/file2.ext",
  "./file1.ext",
  "./file2.ext",
  "./file3.ext",
];
```

I would like to convert it to something like:

```
public class HierarchicalSource{

    public List<HierarchicalSource> Children = new List <HierarchicalSource> ();

    public bool folder { get; set; }

    public string FullPath;

    public HierarchicalSourceSource(string path) {

        this.FullPath = path;

    }

}
```

Where HierarchicalSource is the root, and has a list of children

UPDATE:

I ended up changing the list to a dictionary. There must be a more efficient way to do this, but I did as follows:

```
 string fileList = files.Select(x => x.Remove(0, 2)).ToArray();


                var root = new HierarchicalSource("root");

                foreach(var f in fileList){

                var current = root;
                    string[] splitFile = f.Split('/');
                    foreach(var s in splitFile){
                        if(!current.Children.ContainsKey(s)){


                        current.Children.Add(s, new List<HierarchicalSource>{ new HierarchicalSource(s) }); 
                        }

                        current = current.Children[s].Last();

                    }

                }
```

POCO:

```
public class HierarchicalSource{

    public string name;

    public Dictionary<string, List<HierarchicalSource>> Children = new Dictionary<string, List<HierarchicalSource>>();

    public HierarchicalSource(string name){

        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: So...., show us what you've tried. TIP: Split the string on `/` and iterate the returned array. Search for children. If it doesn't exists, add it.

Comment: Do you think perhaps you could validate your c# code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this requires looping through the array, but it'll allow you to parse each item in the array so you can generate the HierarchicalNode object's values.

```
var node = new HierarchicalSource();

foreach(var str in files)
{
    var pathParts = str.Split('/').ToList();

    node.Children.Add(new HierarchicalNode()
    { 
        FullPath = str,
        Folder = pathParts[1] // you may need to do some debugging to see what the results for pathParts are instead of just [#]
    });
}
```

Since the `FullPath` member in HierarchicalNode is public you can set that value without having to go through any constructor.

```
// using the above code for reference
node.FullPath = whateverThePathYouNeedIs;
```

Also update that property in the class to use getters and setters

```
public string FullPath { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this solution only takes care of the first folder but not subfolders. how would "./Folder/subfolder/subfolder2/file.ext", fit in this scenario?

Comment: In that instance, you can look through that array `pathParts`. It'll break up the strings in your array, and then you just have to sift through `pathParts` to get all the subfolders.